# Перенос данных из input в другой input

Tags: javascript

Предыстория: 
Использую стороннюю платформу и не могу редактировать некоторые базовые элементы, но могу добавлять свои и взаимодействовать с ними при помощи js

Суть в следующем есть вот такой код

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" required="">
<input type="hidden" name="formParams[getNumber]">
<input type="hidden" class="f-input" name="formParams[phone]" >
```

Суть в следующем. Первый инпут заполняет человек, во втором инпуте срабатывает скрипт который берет номер пользователя и преобразует его международный формат. Это уже реализовано

А вот как передать значения из 2 инпута в 3, что бы отправить эти данные в бд, не знаю, уже голову всю поломал. Потому что именно ко второму инпуту у меня нету доступа, а отправка в бд срабатывает по name="formParams[phone]".

Comment: К сожалению платформа не дает скрипту сработать верно.

Comment: Плагин который делает интернациональные номера может выдавать значение в <p> сразу после верного ввода номера, но значения из <p> не передаются в input после появления

Comment: <p  id="output"></p>

<input type="tel" id="phone"  required="">
<input class="f-input" name="formParams[phone]" >

Comment: http://joxi.ru/DmBMR9nUzygpgr

Comment: получается пишем в 1, появляется в 2, переносим в 3

Comment: Не совсем понятно. В текущем варианте, что Вы указали в вопросе - оба ответа являются корректными. Правильно я понимаю, что  сначала вводится номер в 1 поле, и только после полного введения номер появляется во втором?

Comment: Да, верно. вот тут глянуть можно http://514.weborob-it.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если срабатывает событие `change` у `formParams[getNumber]`, и вас понимать буквально:

```
document.querySelector('[name="formParams[getNumber]"]').addEventListener('change', function(){
    document.querySelector('[name="formParams[phone]"]').value = this.value;
})
```

Если событие не срабатывает, то его можно инициировать самостоятельно:

```js
document.querySelector('[name="formParams[getNumber]"]').addEventListener('change', function(){
    document.querySelector('[name="formParams[phone]"]').value = this.value;
    console.log(document.querySelector('[name="formParams[phone]"]').value);
})

document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('change', function(){
    document.querySelector('[name="formParams[getNumber]"]').value = this.value;
    document.querySelector('[name="formParams[getNumber]"]').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="phone" required="">
<input type="hidden" name="formParams[getNumber]">
<input type="hidden" class="f-input" name="formParams[phone]" >
```

Comment: К сожалению платформа не дает скрипту сработать верно.
Плагин который делает интернациональные номера может выдавать значение в <p> сразу после верного ввода номера, но значения из <p> не передаются в input после появления   
<p id="output"></p> <input type="tel" id="phone" required=""> <input class="f-input" name="formParams[phone]" > 
joxi.ru/DmBMR9nUzygpgr 
получается пишем в 1, появляется в 2, переносим в 3

Comment: вот тут можете глянуть http://514.weborob-it.com/

Comment: Не понял, не вы обрабатываете событие переноса значения из 1 в 2? Доступ к этому коду не имеете?

Comment: Как вы можете отловить событие change, input или что-нибудь?

Comment: я использую вот этот плагин.https://intl-tel-input.com/ но связываюсь напрямую с файлами которые у разработчика лежат, так как не могу положить их на платформу.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxWM1Vt1EVZj2

Comment: А что мешает в handleChange добавить снизу `document.querySelector('[name="formParams[phone]"]').value = text;`

Comment: Сработало! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // При загрузке документа
        let phone = document.querySelector('#phone');
        let getNum = document.querySelector('[name="formParams[getNumber]"]');
        let formPhone = document.querySelector('[name="formParams[phone]');
        phone.oninput = function () {
            getNum.value = 'Формат телефона - 8' + this.value; // Тут добавляется формат
            formPhone.value = getNum.value; // Записываем значение из второго поля в третье.
            console.log(formPhone.value);
        }
    })
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="phone" required="">
<input type="hidden" name="formParams[getNumber]">
<input type="hidden" class="f-input" name="formParams[phone]" >
```

В случае, если значение появляется во втором поле только после полного ввода номера в первом - Вы можете использовать событие `blur`:

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // При загрузке документа
        let phone = document.querySelector('#phone');
        let getNum = document.querySelector('[name="formParams[getNumber]"]');
        let formPhone = document.querySelector('[name="formParams[phone]');
        phone.addEventListener('blur', function () {
            getNum.value = 'Формат номер - '+this.value;
            formPhone.value = getNum.value; // Записываем значение из второго поля в третье.
            console.log(formPhone.value);
        });
    })
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="phone" required="">
<input type="hidden" name="formParams[getNumber]">
<input type="hidden" class="f-input" name="formParams[phone]" >
```

Comment: @Leonid Ну да,  Там я специально указал надпись `Формат телефона - 8`&, в `getNum.value = 'Формат телефона - 8' + this.value; // Тут добавляется формат`  Так как ТС не указал какой формат у него указывается при замене. Чтобы было видно, что данные берутся не из первого поля, а уже из второго )

Comment: Ну ясно, а я то думал баг закрался какой...